# Stripe: How to manage user-to-user payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using [Stripe](https://stripe.com) API for a project.

My requirement is users using my app can pay some tips or service fees to other serving users. So basically it is a kind of user-to-user payment.
I have tried everything I can and I am searching on the Internet. But didn't find anything helpful.

Is it possible to do using Stripe?

I am new to Stripe. I have used PayPal before to achieve the same.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already referred that.

Comment: Connect is how you do it, you create a charge and you set the destination as some other Stripe Account

Comment: Yes. And for that user have to connect stripe account for getting paid and also provide credit card or bank info for being charged. I think this is the only solution.

Comment: correct the only solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Stripe very well, but with most of the payment service providers you could only enter one account number to which the payments will be paid. This for security reasons so other people can't receive your payments by simply hacking a config value with the users' account number.